# Is it safe to store an objective-c block in a std::function?

Tags: objective-c++, clang++

I would like to pass a callback block from my objective-C++ code to a C++ object. It's very straightforward since I'm able to assign a block to a std::function. In my mini example everything worked fine, but I'm still uncertain if it's safe to do that.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#include <functional>

std::function<void(void)> f;


@interface T : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString* value;
@end

@implementation T
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}
@end


@implementation ViewController


- (IBAction)storeBlock:(UIButton *)sender {
    T* t = [[T alloc] init];
    t.value = @"the captured obj";
    f = ^void(void) { NSLog(@"This is the block with %@", t.value); };
}

- (IBAction)useBlock:(UIButton *)sender {
    f();
}

- (IBAction)releaseBlock:(UIButton *)sender {
    f = nullptr;
}


@end
```

I've learned that the blocks are stored on the stack and I have to copy it to the heap if I want to use it further than the scope of the block's creation (which I haven't done in my example explicitly). I'm also uncertain how ARC can handle this situation. Is it 'officialy' allowed to do this? I'm using Xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C blocks become invalid when execution leaves the scope where the block is defined. To avoid this, the copy method must be used on the block, that's all.

Comment: For now I learned that ARC inserts a Block_copy call whenever assigning a block to a variable. That's the reason why my example code worked, despite I've used the block after it's creation scope. However the reference counting mechanism (with a std::function involved) is still mysterious to me. What makes the block to be released?

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are treated like normals objects despite the fact, that they start their lifetime on the stack. Like you said, in objc-cpp we can easily store a block in a std::function :-)

So what happens in your example? 
You declared the std::function "f" as a global stack object. When the block is assigned to it, the reference count from the block object is 1. Your "T"-object has in the storeBlock function before leaving two references on it. One by "t" and one through the capturing mechanism from the block. Leaving the scope, only the blocks reference remains. 
Then "f" is set to nullptr: There is no reference to the block object -> the block gets dealloced and with it the "T"-object, because it points a reference to it neither.